Explanation of an inequality in proof of nested intervals property
I am having trouble understand part of a proof of Nested intervals property:
Let $F$ be an ordered field with the monotone sequences property. Let $I_1\supseteq I_2 \supseteq \cdots$ be closed bounded non-empty intervals. Then $\bigcap_{n = 1}^\infty I_n \not= \emptyset$.
Proof:

Let $T_n = [a_n, b_n]$ for each $n$. Then $a_1 \leq a_2 \leq\cdots$ and $b_1 \geq b_2\geq \cdots$. For each $n$, $a_n \leq b_n \leq b_1$. So the sequence $a_n$ is bounded above. So by the monotone sequences property, it has a limit $a$. For each $n$, we must have $a_n\leq a$. Otherwise, say $a_n > a$. Then for all $m \geq n$, we have $a_m \geq a_n > a$. This implies that $a > a$, which is nonsense.
Also, for each fixed $n$, we have that $\forall m\geq n$, $a_m \leq b_m \leq b_n$. So $a \leq b_n$. Thus, for all $n$, $a_n \leq a \leq b_n$. So $a\in I_n$. So $a\in \bigcap_{n = 1}^\infty I_n$.

For last part, how do we go from $a_m \leq b_m \leq b_n$ to $a \leq b_n$?
I already have $a_n \leq a$ and $b_1 \geq \dots \geq b_n$ (by definition), but for some reason I don't see where they get $a \leq b_n$ from. Can someone help a beginner?

As $a_n \leq b_n$ for all $n$. and also both the limit exists so taking limit $n \to \infty$ on both side we get $a \leq b$.
Now, as $(a_n)$ is a monotonic increasing sequence bounded above and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \sup a_n$.
Also, observe that
$(b_n)$ is a monotonic decreasing sequence bounded below and $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = \inf b_n$.
Hence we can write that $a_1 \leq a_2 \leq \cdots\leq a\leq b \leq \cdots \leq b_2 \leq b_1$.

$\forall m\geq n$, $a_m \leq b_m \leq b_n$, gives $a_m\leq b_n$ for all $m>n$ so letting $m\to\infty$ gives $\lim_{m\to\infty}a_m\leq b_n.$

Can I ask why are we allowed to take limit on one side only? I thought it works if we only take limits on both sides, i.e., $\lim_{m\to\infty}a_{m}\leq  \lim_{n\to\infty}b_{n}$
